# Column type is not supported for List<>

Tags: flutter, sqlite, foreign-keys

I use [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) as SQLite abstraction in a flutter app.

I want to save a person with a list of presents, so I created a ForeignKey (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/vitusortner/floor/issues/221)) and mapped child `id` to parent `presents`, but I get the error `Column type is not supported for List<Present>` when I run the generator via `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`.

I have present and person as entities.

```dart
@entity
class Present {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? id;
  String name;
  double? price;

  Present({this.id, required this.name, this.price});
}
```

```dart
@Entity(tableName: 'Person', foreignKeys: [
  ForeignKey(childColumns: ['id'], parentColumns: ['presents'], entity: Present)
])
class Person {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? id;
  String name;
  List<Present> presents;

  Person({
    this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.presents,
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in floor you cant use complex types as properties to model relationships. Look at https://github.com/pinchbv/floor/blob/develop/docs/entities.md ... just the plain foreign key is referenced here. There is still an open `@Relation` annotation feature request open, but it isn't implemented as far as i know. Instead you might have to load and map the relations by yourself.